# How to Show Different Sized Image on Mobile in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I want to do something that I *thought* would be extremely simple: show an image at `200px` x `200px`, unless the screen size is `< 500px`, in which case show it at `100px` x `100px` instead.

This seems like the most basic responsive design one could have: just one image, with two different dimensions based on screen size ... but it *seems* impossible just using Next's `<Image>` tag.  That tag has tons of related props (`sizes`, `loader`, `srcSet` ... plus the `deviceSizes` and `imageSizes` in the Next config) ... but none of them seem to let me achieve this basic goal.

I eventually got things working by:

1. starting with an `Image` that uses `layout="fill"` and
   `objectFit="cover"`
2. wrapping it with a `<div>` that has `max-width` and `max-height`
   (and min-width/height also) of `200px`
3. adding a media query to change the styles in #2 to `100px` below
   `500px` screen width

... but this feels like I'm just throwing out all of the power of the `<Image>` and rewriting my own component, and I don't get Next to automatically resize my images this way.

Is there any simpler way to get the same effect (again, same image, just two different dimensions, controlled by screen size) using the `<Image>` tag directly (and not just styling the `<div>` around it)?

Comment: I'd recommend having a look at the new [`next/future/image`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/future/image) component, which gives you more control to style the `<img>` element directly.

Comment: *sound of trumpets, angles sing, "Hallelujah"*

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a wrapping `className={logoContainer}` for `<Image>`, i.e.

```
import style from 'styles/Logo.module.css';

<div className={`mx-auto ${style.logoContainer}`>
  <Image className={style.logo} src={logo} alt="logo" />
</div>
```

and with the css (my case with bootstrap classes):

```
.logoContainer {
  width: 60px;
  height: 42px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .logoContainer {
    width: 65px;
    height: 46px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .logoContainer {
    width: 90px;
    height: 63px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, but as the last line of my question stated, " (and not just styling the <div> around it)?"  It's sounding like the answer to this question should maybe be "no, the Next Image component doesn't work on its own, you *need* to wrap it with a div to use it".

Comment: It is true, I missed the last sentence. It looks like @juliomalves has figured out the answer: using ```next/future/image```